# Strange behaviour on ViewModel property, RaisePropertyChanged not being executed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I've noticed a strange behaviour with RaisePropertyChanged while adding objects to a ViewModel property.

```
private List<string> _items;
public List<string> Items
{
    get 
    {
        if(_items == null){ _items = new List<string>(); } 
        return _itmes; 
    }
    set
    {
        _items = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
    }
}
```

When ever I add objects to the collection through the property

```
Items.Add("new string");
```

RaisePropertyChanged never gets called.

What is the best way of getting the RaisePropertyChanged to function the way that I would like it to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your setter will be called when you change the collection, not if the contents of the collection has been changed.
What you need is a collection that informs you about changes. Look at the [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)-class. Register to its [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) event for beeing informed about changes.

**Property with a setter**
The following example shows you how you can work with a settable property that holds an observable collection. The complexity of the example is because the collection can be set from the outsite of the instance. If you don't need this feature, the solution will get be much more simple.

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _items;
public ObservableCollection<string> Items {
    get {
        if (_items == null) { 
           // Create a new collection and subscribe to the event
           Items=new ObservableCollection<string>(); 
        }
        return _items;
    }
    set {
      if(value !=_items){
        if (null != _items) {
            // unsubscribe for the old collection
            _items.CollectionChanged -= new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(_items_CollectionChanged);
        }
        _items = value;
        if (null != _items) {
            // subscribe for the new collection
            _items.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(_items_CollectionChanged);    
        }
        // Here you will be informed, when the collection itselfs has been changed
        RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
    }
  }
}

void _items_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    // Here you will be informed, if the content of the collection has been changed.  
}
```

**Property without a setter**
If you don't need to have the collection setable, register to `CollectionChanged` while creating the collection. However you have then to remove the setter of your property. Otherwise will not be informed of changes if the collection has been changed:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _items; 
public ObservableCollection<string> Items {
    get {
        if (_items == null) { 
           // Create a new collection and subscribe to the event
           _items=new ObservableCollection<string>(); 
           _items.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler
        }
        return _items;
    }
}

void _items_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    // Here you will be informed, if the content of the collection has been changed.  
}
```

**Additional information**
Look at [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx)  for further information about collection changes. The above examples you also can use more generic with `IEnumerable<string>` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it never gets called because you are actually not setting the property (the setter of Items property is not getting called) when you add an item to the collection.

In case of collection modification what you need is to raise a CollectionChanged event. For this purpose you need to use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of usual `List<T>`:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _items;
public ObservableCollection<string> Items
{
    get 
    {
        if(_items == null){ _items = new ObservableCollection<string>(); } 
        return _itmes; 
    }
    set
    {
        _items = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
    }
}
```

Now, when you add items to the collection, the `CollectionChanged` event will be raised and your UI will get updated accordingly.